# TYPO3 cannot access backend anywhere but on my own computer

Tags: typo3

I cannot access TYPO3 backend anywhere but on my own computer?
If I go to www.domain.com/typo3 I get the frontpage of the site. But if I go to www.domain.com/typo3 on my own computer it works fine.

Can TYPO3 have saved my IP address somewhere or what?

Comment: you need to configure your typoscript. in setup - 
config.baseURL = http:// www.domain.com
config.absRefPrefix = /

Comment: Is it a new installation?
Please paste the content of /typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible in many ways. Have a look here: http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/SecurityGuide/GuidelinesIntegrators/GlobalTypo3Options/Index.html

Comment: I have now tried different things, but anywhere, except at my own ip address, www.domain.com/typo3 is blank.